Closure of specialization of points of an affine group scheme with smooth generic fiber
Let $R$ be a henselian discrete valuation ring with residue field $k$, and let $G$ be an affine faithfully-flat finite type group scheme over $R$ with smooth generic fiber. Let $R'$ be the ring of integers of the maximal unramified extension of $\operatorname{Frac} R$, with residue field $k'$. Let $H$ be the Zariski closure of the image of the specialization map $G(R')\rightarrow G(k')$. This is a closed subscheme of $G_k$.
It's claimed in Kaletha–Prasad's book Bruhat–Tits theory, Appendix A.6 (Construction A.6.1), that $H$ is a smooth subgroup scheme of the special fiber $G_{k}$.
Why is this the case? Do smooth points in the generic fiber have to specialize to smooth points of the special fiber? Why is the closure a subgroup scheme?

I think that the point is that the Zariski closure of the rational points of a group scheme (not just a scheme) over a separably closed field (like $k'$) is always smooth.  See Conrad, Gabber, and Prasad - Pseudo-reductive groups, Lemma C.4.1.

@LSpice Thanks for the reference! This settles the smoothness part. From this, Kaletha-Prasad's claim would follow if the closure of a subgroup of $G_{k'}(k')$ in $G_{k'}$ is a subgroup scheme whose $k'$-points are exactly $G_{k'}(k')$. Is this true?

Re, I think you mean "the closure of $G_{k'}(k')$ in $G_{k'}$", not "… a subgroup of …".  Then yes, it is true.  (Rational points is, I'd argue, reasonably obvious, since you certainly haven't lost any, and since your subgroup of $G_{k'}$ can't have more rational points than $G_{k'}$ itself.)  This is part of the same result.  I'll go ahead and post it as an answer, and you can let me know if it doesn't suffice.

@LSpice I actually did mean "...a subgroup of...", since the closure described in the OP is the closure of the image of the specialization map, which is typically not the entirety of $G(k')$.

Re, oh, I see; my apologies.  But I don't see it claimed in Construction A.6.1 that the closure has all the rational points of $G_{k'}$, only that it is a smooth subgroup scheme thereof.

@LSpice I don't claim that in the OP either!

Re, agreed, but you seemed to want it in the comment, so I was confused.  Or was your point that it's needed to use Lemma C.4.1 directly as written? If the latter, then I guess you want the bit of Lemma C.4.1 that proves geometric reducedness, which to me is too terse ("as we may see by reducing to the case of affine $X$ and using injectivity of the natural map $K'\otimes_K\prod V_i\to\prod(K'\otimes_KV_i)$ for any field extension $K'/K$ and any indexed collection of $K$-vector spaces $V_i$").

@LSpice Sorry! I see what you mean. In the comment you quoted, the sentence ending "whose $k'$-points are exactly $G_{k'}(k')$.", it should instead read: "whose $k'$-points are exactly that subgroup of $G_{k'}(k')$". Sorry about that.

Re, ah, that makes sense.  I have expanded on my terse original answer without, however, addressing this latter question, because I don't know the answer, and it seems not to be needed.

I originally thought that our comments 1 2 3 suggested that Lemma C.4.1 of [CGP]: Conrad, Gabber, and Prasad - Pseudo-reductive groups might answer your question:

Let $X$ be a scheme locally of finite type over a field $k$.  There is a unique geometrically reduced closed subscheme $X^\natural \subseteq X$ such that $X^\natural(k') = X(k')$ for all separable extensions $k'/k$.  The formation of $X^\natural$ is functorial in $X$ and commutes with the formation of products over $k$ and separable extensions of the ground field.  In particular, if $X$ is a $k$-group scheme then $X^\natural$ is a smooth $k$-subgroup scheme.

However, you point out that we are taking  the Zariski closure not necessarily of $G(k')$, but possibly of some proper subgroup.  So it seems to me that I might wind up needing to reproduce the proof.
Let me right up front observe that a $\operatorname{Gal}(k'/k)$-stable subgroup scheme of $G_{k'}$ descends uniquely to a subgroup scheme of $G_k$, so there is no harm in replacing $R$ by $R'$ in the first place.  Thus we'll assume that $k$ is separably closed.
The proof of geometric reducedness, which seems to be the key, is rather terse:

… we may see [geometric reducedness] by reducing to the case of affine $X$ and using injectivity of the natural map $K' \otimes_K \prod V_i \to \prod (K' \otimes_K V_i)$ for any field extension $K'/K$ and any indexed collection of $K$-vector spaces $V_i$.

I suppose the point here is to apply this to vector spaces $V_x = k[\{x\}]$ indexed by the points $x$ of $X(k)$, i.e., the $k$-algebra homomorphisms $x \colon k[X] \to k$.  I'm not quite sure what to do with these, but it seems to me that one can just think concretely that, if an element $f$ of $k[X] \otimes_k k_\text a$ and a positive integer $n$ are such that $f^n$ vanishes on a point $x \in X(k)$, i.e., if $f^n(x) = x(f^n) = x(f)^n$ is trivial, then $x(f)$ is trivial, because it lies in the reduced ring $k_\text a$.  Probably that's a clumsy version of the same argument.  This argument works equally well even if we take only some, not all, of the $k$-points of $X$, so I believe that there's no problem there.
Let me go ahead and steal the symbology of [CGP], and denote the Kaletha–Prasad construction (which makes perfectly good sense for any scheme, not just group schemes) by $(\cdot)_k^\natural$.  It is clear that this is functorial (for scheme morphisms), so $G_k^\natural$ is closed under taking inverses, and $(G \times G)_k^\natural$ is contained in $G_k^\natural \times G_k^\natural$.  On the other hand, since $\operatorname{im}(G(R) \to G(k)) \times \operatorname{im}(G(R) \to G(k)) = \operatorname{im}((G \times G)(R) \to (G \times G)(k))$ is contained in the closed subscheme $(G \times G)_k^\natural$ of $(G \times G)_k$, so is its closure $G_k^\natural \times G_k^\natural$.  Thus we have equality $G_k^\natural \times G_k^\natural = (G \times G)_k^\natural$, and so a functorial map $G_k^\natural \times G_k^\natural \to G_k^\natural$ coming from the multiplication on $G$.  Since $G_k^\natural$ clearly contains the identity element, it is a subgroup scheme of $G_k$.  Since it is geometrically reduced, it is smooth.

Hmm this argument seems to imply that the closure of any subset of $k_s$-points of a $k$-scheme is geometrically reduced. Is this true?

@stupid_question_bot, re, I agree, it does seem to imply that.  My algebraic geometry is so weak that I don't know whether that is plausible or im-, but my argument is so concrete that, if it is wrong, then it indicates a very fundamental misunderstanding of geometric reduced-ness on my part (which is not at all implausible).  It does seem like CGP might have remarked on it if it were so.  I would like to see if I could directly modify their proof, but, as I say, I can't manage to unravel its details.
